# Realm Write Transaction takes 1 mins 20 secs

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I have a four objects which are User, Subsection, Section and Department. 
Please check the class diagram. [image: here]

Currently the data structure is like this.

**Department.m**

```
@implementation Department

- (id)initWithData:(NSDictionary*)data {

    if (self = [super init]) {

        self.name = data[@"name"];
        self.isCollapsed = 0;
        self.isSearchCollapsed = 1;

        for (NSDictionary *dict in data[@"sections"])
        {
            Section *section = [[Section alloc] initWithData:dict andDepartmentName:self.name];
            [self.sections addObject:section];

            for (SubSection *subSection in section.sections)
            {
                [self.subSections addObject:subSection];
            }
        }

        for (NSDictionary *dict in data[@"userlist"])
        {
            User *user = [[User alloc] initWithData:dict withLoggedIn:NO];
            [self.users addObject:user];
        }

    }
    return self;
}

+ (NSString *)primaryKey {
    return @"name";
}

@end
```

**Department.h**

```
@interface Department : RLMObject

@property NSString *name;

@property (nonatomic, strong) RLMArray<Section> *sections;
@property (nonatomic, strong) RLMArray<SubSection> *subSections;
@property (nonatomic, strong) RLMArray<User> *users;

@property (nonatomic, strong) RLMArray<Section> *searchSections;
@property (nonatomic, strong) RLMArray<User> *searchUsers;
@end
```

**Section**

```
@interface Section : RLMObject

@property NSString *name;
@property NSString *departmentName;
@property RLMArray<SubSection> *sections;
@property RLMArray<User> *users;
@property (nonatomic, strong) RLMArray<SubSection> *searchSections;
@property (nonatomic, strong) RLMArray<User> *searchUsers;

@end
```

**Subsection**

```
@interface SubSection : RLMObject

@property NSString *name;
@property NSString *sectionName;
@property NSString *departmentName;
@property RLMArray<User> *users;
@property RLMArray<User> *searchUsers;

@end
```

**User**

```
@interface User : RLMObject
@property NSString *department;
@property NSString *email;
@property NSString *firstname;
@property NSString *lastname;
@property NSString *fullname;
@property NSString *section;
@property NSString *subSection;
@end
```

Here is the write transaction. please check.

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    @try
    {
        for (NSDictionary *dict in result)
        {
            Department *department = [[Department alloc] initWithData:dict];
            [realm beginWriteTransaction];
            [realm addOrUpdateObject:department];
            [realm commitWriteTransaction];
        }

        successBlock();
    }
    @catch (NSException * e)
    {
        DLog(@"Exception: %@", e.reason);
        failBlock(e);
    }
```

When I write 
Users - 10660
Sections - 62
Subsection - 156 
Department - 19
to the realm, it takes 1 mins 20 secs even though android takes only 40 seconds. Is there anything that I have to fix? The data structure is same with android and iOS. Users are complaining about this after they check with android.

Comment: So where is the write transaction? But I'm sure replacing some `RLMArray`s with `RLMLinkingObjects` would make it faster.

Comment: I asked the similar question few months ago. Read the answer, it will help you too. It has increased Write Transaction from 9 minutes to 5 seconds. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45075407/how-to-load-thousands-records-to-realm-correctly

Comment: Hello @EpicPandaForce I have edited my question. please check.

Comment: Thanks @V.Khambir. I will check. :)